# Website cannot accept SQL Server CE database file on a web server (WebCentral)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, exception, sql-server-ce

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at
>   this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using  from an
>   inherited configuration file.
>
> ```
> Source Error: 
>
> Line 5:    <system.web>
> Line 6:      <fullTrustAssemblies>
> Line 7:        <add
> Line 8:            assemblyName="System.Data.SqlServerCe"
> ```

Any idea? I feel exhausted after hours and hours searching for viable solutions, but non of them works for me.

Comment: Gosh, no one can answer after nearly 1 hour >_<;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out.

I replaced the fullTrustAssembilies with the partialTrustAssembilies and the error went away.

But another error appears.

It's something about : 
Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods.

And after hours and hours research, I finally got to know that it's not in my ability. But the SQL CE needs to use System.Security.dll to serialize the data.
So either install the SQLCE runtime on the server, or rise the trustLevel to full level.
But none of them can be permitted.

So I have decided to move to SQL Server 2008. >_<;

But I'd really like to know the web hosting servers which has the ability to user MS SQL CE coz it's really convenient for me if I could use only a standalone file database file which doesn't require any other server side components to store my data without purchasing the Add-on services.

Answer (score 0):

The administrator of the web server must enable trust in the global web config to support SQL Server Compact. Please chekc with your hosting provider that this is the case.

Comment: I called them, and pressed 2 to talk to a technical consultant. After she listened to my question, she told me that she will transfer me to another one. And I waited for 1 hour and 26 mins, when I was finally in the 1st of queue, my connection was cut off.....What @#$%#$# web host!!!